# Best practice for form fields with interdependent dropdown menus

Tags: dropdown

I have a best practice question. I have a form field that has questions with drop downs. Some of the dropdowns answers would make fields appear or disappear. My question is, should all fields be visible when you open the page or should they be loaded by sections depending on what the user chooses in the dropdown menu.[image]

Comment: Is the default option "All" or similar that would show all the fields?

Comment: Hi, so basically i open this webpage with a starting dropdown question, and depending on what you choose the following question would appear. Now it is not decided if the next questions should appear or be there already but disabled. There is also the problem if all questions would be visible but disabled, some of them might not be available anyway unless you choose some upper reply to a question first. I dont know if i am explaining myself correclty.

Answer (score 1):

Progressive display appears to be the most sensible here; opening only what's needed based on user response.

However... what you're really creating are "modes" that get experienced based on varying choices. Even though your questions may seem clear enough, users might either a) still not be wholly sure what to choose or b) choose to explore various choices anyway. So, I'm suggesting you make it easy should a user switch paths. (Which they could conceivably also do by accident.) For example, if possible, hold on to answers to sub questions even if they switch paths. This way, they don't lose their work. You only have to send the correct set of answers on form submission, but don't lose prior entries. Let's leave aside any formal studies for a moment and consider your own web experience: How many times have you looked at or used a form and then gone another way, come back, and been annoyed by having to re-enter info?

Progress Bar: Since there's hidden work to be done, if it's more than a few questions, perhaps include a progress bar at the top. This only make sense if the depth is about equal for all question paths. Doing this kind of thing helps set user expectations. It also slightly "gamifies" the system. This method is known to increase completion rates of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one section opened in the start which is of greater importance i.e.,  in terms of usability, or mandatory ones so that the user is not confused on seeing large set of data at a time.

---

and the second point is about auto hide all other sections on opening a new one(until there is some requirement of previous section on the new ones). if such is the case maintain the same interaction throughout.

Comment: Thanks for that so as an example : What service do you use ( mobile / fixed ) and when he chooses mobile the section appears underneath with the next question ( what bandwith ) and then when a choice is made the next question appears ( what device ) and so on. Sounds inline with what I was going to do. Cheers.